# source code for search engine

Tags: search-engine, web-crawler

i want to implement a search engine.Is there any source code available for it in python etc...
i know there are tools for it like spinx etc. but i would like to have my own code running. may i know if there is any source code for it.

Comment: Do you want to make a search spider/web-crawler or a search engine for your own website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/)?

Comment: That looks like a wrapper around a Java library, so the Python source won't have anything interesting. Even worse, it looks like it's generated by a tool.

Comment: Writing your own search engine is a complicated task, especially if you want features like relevance, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Apache Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) , which is  Web Crawler and search engine integrated with Apache Solr.

It also supports Hadoop, Distributed Crawling.